# CAN Resistor Location Help

Tags: resistors, can, network

Having discussion at work today and wondered if someone could help clear my mind.

We are creating an RS432 network to control 3 aircon units.

The network requires termination using 120 ohm resistors, and it was suggested to me that we can put these resistors in parallel at the point of connection to the final unit.

Is this OK as I thought it had to be end of line, so placing the resistors at the point of connection would cause an issue?

Simply put, does it matter where the 2 x 120 ohm resistors go in the network as long as the backbone has 60 ohm resistance?

I apologise for my lack of knowledge, just trying to learn!

Comment: Do you mean RS-422?

Comment: RS432 and CAN are not similar in any way. RS422 and CAN are similar but different. Which one you mean?

Comment: If you don't even know which technology you are using, there is no hope of you ever successfully designing a product containing that technology either.

Comment: RS-432 doesn't exist. Unfortunately it fits as typo for RS-232, RS-422 and RS-423.

Answer (score 1):

The necessity for those resistance is to dampen the reflection over a long transmission line. Placing them on one end only will be effective to remove reflection in only that direction instead of both. I would definitely advise to put them at both ends.

Comment: We definitely intend to fit 2, but it's the specific location. If the resistor is in parallel with the connection into the unit, is it truly on the "end" and will this have a negative effect?

Comment: That's what I explained. Placing both resistor on one side of your transmission line won't prevent the reflections properly.

Answer (score 1):

In a high speed (11898-2) CAN bus, the backbone should be a single, long, twisted pair, with one resistor connected at each end (two ends, total two resistors).

It should be a single line topology. It should not branch, or star, or circle back on itself.

The CAN transceivers can connect to any point on this line, in the middle, or at an end. There is a limit to how long the connection, the stub, may be between CAN transceiver and the bus.

In a low speed (11898-3) bus, the termination resistors can be sited at the nodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffsfs3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>